# asp.net blog engine which supports themes?

Tags: asp.net, blogs, blogengine.net

Looking for a open source mature ASP.NET based blog engine which supports themes. I was working with [BlogEngine](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net) but I am finding that  some of HTML produced is different than the declared ones I have in files and I am spending too much time troubleshooting these issues.

Is there another blog engine? [dasBlog](http://www.dasblog.info) latest update was March 2009. I am not sure if this means that its abandoned or the developers think it's done? 17 months is a long time for an open source project with many contributors.

Next is subText. Any other ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graffiti CMS it is not per se a blog engine but it could be used as such. It got open-sourced recently. The documentation states the following about themes:

> Graffiti provides you with a lot of
>   flexibility for rendering different
>   content based on the page site
>   requested. Remaining true to the
>   mantra of "Convention over
>   Configuration", Graffiti provides the
>   themes feature so you can specify
>   different view files per page or
>   section of the site without ever
>   having to tell Graffiti they exist.

Last push is from end july 2010:
[image]

Comment: I have decided to stay with BlogEngine and start over in a cleaner way. I figured this would be faster than learning a new blog software.

Comment: Yes, it is more often than not a safer decision. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://atomsite.net/
Pretty cool that its all based on open standards. Supports themes.

Making themes for atomsite:
http://atomsite.net/info/Themes.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

- Atomsite: http://atomsite.net/
- SubText: http://subtextproject.com/
- Orchard: http://www.orchardproject.net/